# Prove that if $G$ and $H$ is Hamiltonian then $G \times H$ is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ and $H$ is Hamiltonian then the Cartesian product $G \times H$ is Hamiltonian

> Theorem 3.16: If $G$ is Hamiltonian and $S$ is the vertex cut then
>
> $$k(G-S) \leq |S|$$

This what I got so far

Assume that $G$ of order $n$ and $H$  of order $m$ are Hamiltonian . Let $u \in V(G)$ and $v\in V(H)$.

I know that $G\times H$ has order $nm$ and $deg(u,v)=deg(u) +deg(v) $

But I want to show that $deg(u,v)=deg(u) +deg(v) \geq \frac{nm}{2}$. How can I do that from here? I don't think theorem 3.16 help, because I don't know which kind of graph $G$ and $H$ are.

Comment: You can't assume that $deg(u) \geq n/2$, since it's only a sufficient condition for Hamiltonicity (it's not necessary).  Take the cycle graph $C_n$ for instance.  It's Hamiltonian but every vertex is of degree 2.  Now, can you specify which product $G \times H$ refers to ?  Various people use it for various products...

Comment: A proof that a product of two Hamiltonian graphs is Hamiltonian also is [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~mne/275/ans1114.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Heavily revised.**

Your statement that $\deg(\langle u,v\rangle)=\deg(u)+\deg(v)$ suggests that the graph product that you have in mind is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs), which I’ve seen denoted both by $\times$ and by $\square$: $<\langle u_0,v_0\rangle$ and $\langle u_1,v_1\rangle$ are adjacent in $G\times H$ iff either $u_0=u_1$ and $v_0$ and $v_1$ are adjacent in $H$, or $v_0=v_1$ and $u_0$ and $u_1$ are adjacent in $G$. If that’s the case, it’s not hard to get a Hamilton cycle in $G\times H$ from Hamilton cycles in $G$ and $H$.

Suppose that $G$ has the cycle $u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_m,u_0$, and $H$ has the cycle $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_0$. Then we can represent $G\times H$ by an $(m+1)\times(n+1)$ rectangular array of vertices, each row and column of which is a cycle in $G\times H$.

If $n$ is odd, we can get a Hamilton cycle like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
v_n&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&&&&&&&&&&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-1}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-2}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&&&&&&&&&&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-1}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&&&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
v_1&\bullet&&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
&\color{blue}\uparrow&&&&&&&&&&&&\downarrow\\
v_0&\bullet&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
&u_0&&u_1&&u_2&&u_3&&\ldots&&u_{m-1}&&u_m
\end{array}$$

If $n$ is even, we do this instead:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
v_n&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&&&&&&&&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-1}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-2}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
&\uparrow&&&&&&&&&&\downarrow\\
v_{n-3}&\bullet&&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&&&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
v_1&\bullet&&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\ldots&\longleftarrow&\bullet&\longleftarrow&\bullet\\
&\color{blue}\uparrow&&\downarrow\\
v_0&\bullet&&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\ldots&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet&\color{red}\longrightarrow\\
&u_0&\color{red}\nwarrow&u_1&&u_2&&\ldots&&u_{m-1}&&u_m&&\color{red}\downarrow\\
&&&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow&\color{red}\longleftarrow
\end{array}$$

In each diagram I’ve started at $\langle u_0,v_0\rangle$ and headed up along the blue edge, finishing along the red edge.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit further please? I still can't see how this make the Cartesian product $G \times H$ Hamiltonian, since I still don't know what are $G$ and $H$.

Comment: @Diane: I really didn’t explain that very well before, so I’ve completely revised and expanded the answer.

Comment: for part $n$ is even, a between $v_{n-3}$ and $v_1$, you go to the right for any even subscript of $v$ and go to the left for odd subscript?

Comment: @Diane: Yes. Once you go up to the top, you just snake back and forth until you reach the bottom.