# Let $C_n$, $C_m$ two cycles, show that $C_n * C_m$ is hamiltonian. Conclude saying that if $G$ and $H$ are hamiltonian then $G x H$ is hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Hi I need to prove this:

Let $C_n$, $C_m$ two cycles, show that $C_n * C_m$ is hamiltonian. Conclude saying that if $G$ and $H$ are hamiltonian then $G x H$ is hamiltonian

But i really don't know where to start, please help! thanks

Comment: A proof that a product of two Hamiltonian graphs is Hamiltonian is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989019/prove-that-if-g-and-h-is-hamiltonian-then-g-times-h-is-hamiltonian) or [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~mne/275/ans1114.pdf).

Comment: @Daniela Velásquez Garzón: Do you mind giving defintions for your symbols? What does $GxH$ mean?

Comment: Product between $G$ and $H$